# How to create an array of objects?

Tags: java, arrays, object

My Question is :

Create a class Student that contains student name, roll number, address, email and phone. From main method create an array of Student objects for your batch and print it. Note that main should be in a different class.

I created two students objects but I don't know how to add it to array.

```
public class Student {

    String name;
    int rollNum;
    String address;
    String email;
    int phoneNum;

}

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Student[] student=new Student[2];
        Student student1=new Student();
        Student student2=new Student();
        student1.name="Pooja";
        student1.rollNum=9164086;
        student1.address="Chennai";
        student1.email="poojasingh@gmail.com";
        student1.phoneNum=232732;
        student2.name="Smriti";
        student2.rollNum=9159999;
        student2.address="Lucknow";
        student2.email="angel.smriti@gmail.com";
        student2.phoneNum=232735;
        student[0]=student1;
        student[1]=student2;
        System.out.print("{");
        for(int i=0;i<student.length;i++){
            if(i>0){
                System.out.print(",");
            }
            System.out.print(student[i]);
        }
        System.out.print("}");
    }
}
```

Comment: You have already done that (`student[0] = student1;`)

Comment: But it is not giving the required output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already added `student1` and `student2` in the array, the problem is that you cannot print an object unless it *overrides* the method: `toString`. But simply do this:

```
System.out.println(student[i].name + ", " + student[i].rollNum + ", " + student[i].address + ", " + student[i].email + ", " + student[i].phoneNum);
```

And delete `if (i>0) {...}` from your for loop.

Or if you want to *override* `toString` just add this piece of code into `Student` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name + ", " + rollNum + ", " + address + ", " + email + ", " + phoneNum;
}
```

And in the main use:

```
for(int i = 0; i < student.lenght; i++) {
    System.out.println(student[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already added the `Student` objects to the array `student`. If the problem is that you are not getting the expected output, the reason is that since they are objects, you have to *override* the `toString` method in the `Student` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;  // for example
}
```

You should return a `String` that shows the relevant information about the object. The method above is just an example, so you may want to change it.